# R plots displaying in different sizes

Tags: r, plot

I'm new to R and have the following code:

```
plot1 = FeaturePlot(objectName, features = c("feature1", "feature2"))
plot2 = FeaturePlot(objectName2, features = c("feature1", "feature2"))
plot1+plot2
```

And the output shows the second plot under the first plot but it's only 1/2 the width. is there anyway to make the plots the same width?

Comment: What package does `FeaturePlot` come from? What kind of objects are `objectName` and `objectName2`. ?

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Sorry - didn't think that mattered.  FeaturePlot is from Seurat and objectName is just the name of the object I'm plotting.